# How to add SSD to Dual Booted PC

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd

I currently have a HP Pavilion 590-a0000 Desktop PC series which came with 1 TB of HDD. I want to purchase a 500GB SSD drive to use as a sole drive for my ubuntu Install. I want to clone everything from my current dual booted ubuntu and move it to the SSD then after it is moved I will delete it off the HDD which it shares with Windows 10.

1. Is it possible to install SSD alongside HDD with my particular PC.
2. What is the best way to go about this?

Thank you.

Comment: I normally suggest a new install and restore from your backups. Good test that backups are complete as you still have old install to go back to if something missing. Backups should include /home & list of installed apps. And any system settings you change in /etc. I edit grub, but just copy into /home so backup of /home includes that. If any server type apps in / you also need those. Drive order also important with Ubiquity installer. Use lower SATA port for new SSD.

Answer (score 0):

I had dual boot on a 525GB Sata SSD and needed to clone to a 512GB NVME SSD drive.

In my case, I managed to shrink one of the partitions and do the selective cloning by Macrium Reflect.

Now, the 525GB Sata SSD is my second drive.

Comment: I currently have 1TB HDD though, would that matter? I want to run both the HDD and SSD at the same time, is this possible?

Comment: Yes ... I had a desktop PC before my notebook and used a 240GB SSD along with a 2TB HDD

Comment: did you follow a specific tutorial? I am unsure how to go about actually installing the SSD alongside my HDD. Thanks!